# GC.TryStartNoGCRegion throws when previous usage exceeded its declared allocations

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I can't find a way to call `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion` if the previous usage exceeded its declared allocations. In that case `GC.EndNoGCRegion` throws as per documentation, and a new call to `TryStartNoGCRegion` throws also:

```
        GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(1000*10000);

        //Allocate more than declared
        for (int i = 0; i < 1100; i++)
        {
            var arr = new byte[10000];
        }

        //Line below throws as it should
        //System.GC.EndNoGCRegion();

        //Not NoGCRegion
        Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.GCSettings.LatencyMode);

        //Throws with "The NoGCRegion mode was already in progress
        GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(1000*10000);
```

How to start the no GC mode again?

Comment: Are you sure the first `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion` call returned true?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, I've just checked it again to be certain. If it didn't, I can't imagine the second call failing with "NoGCRegion mode was already in progress"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(1000 * 10000);

    //Allocate more than declared
    for (int i = 0; i < 1100; i++)
    {
        var arr = new byte[10000];
    }

    //Line below throws as it should
    try
    {
        System.GC.EndNoGCRegion();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    //Not NoGCRegion
    Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.GCSettings.LatencyMode);

    //Throws with "The NoGCRegion mode was already in progress
    Console.WriteLine(GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(1000 * 10000));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The apparent difference is the necessity to call `EndNoGCRegion` (and swallow exceptions) before trying to call `TryStartNoGCRegion` again.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old issue, anyway, I just wanted to leave a note that this is a bug, and it is already fixed in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/73602) PR with [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/5f80c24a6600e9d52a84f22d7b6088fe63180cee) commit. The fix is available for .NET Core 3.1 or above.